# Kubernetes admission controller for network policy

Tags: networking, controller, kubernetes, policy

I was working on back-fitting some security policies on name spaces in our cluster but after a while I realized that this will be all lost time and effort if I'm not able to enforce all new name spaces to have some network policies configured upon creation.

I looked into admission controllers but seems like there is nothing ready, out of the box to accomplish this task (enforce network policies when creating a new name space). The only feasible way seems to be using Admission Webhooks that would delegate the decision to service I'd have to write.

Is my understanding correct or is there other way, perhaps simpler/smarter to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of network policies you want to apply during new namespace creation?

Comment: We've got some standard network policies that provide base layer for security and allow most of the expected communication to take place (allow access only to known ports, allow DNS queries, allow ingress to services and communication inside of the namespace. Ban everything else. This kind of thing. Why?